# Visual Studio Code is detecting wrongly that I don't need a using C# / .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I'm using Visual Studio Code with [C# Microsoft Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp). I also have the following setting to format and fix all issues each time I save a file:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.sortMembers": true
},
```

I'm working on a .NET Core project and I don't know why Visual Studio Code is detecting that some usings are not being used which is wrong. Because of that, each time I save a file, the usings are being removed. I'm positive about this because the compiler let me know that I'm missing usings each time I run `dotnet build`.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue without changing the `codeActionsOnSave` setting that I have in place?

Software versions:

- [C# Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp): v1.25.7
- .NET Core version: 7.0.202

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that fixed my issues but compromises having `"source.fixAll"` on c# files:

1. Open your `settings.json` file. *click here to learn how to do it*
2. Add the following code:

```js
{
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true,
      "source.fixAll": true,
      "source.sortMembers": true
    }
  }
}
```